# Is this computer compatible with Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: dell-vostro

I want to buy a new computer - this computer
https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/new-vostro-14-5402-laptop/spd/vostro-14-5402-laptop/smv145w10p2c3003tp
Is Ubuntu suitable for it in terms of video card, network card, sound card and the like?
Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas-Ward this is not duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop.I'm read it.

Comment: "I want to buy a new computer" - "is Ubuntu sutiable for [this computer]" - sounds like you're asking whether your system meets the requirements to use Ubuntu.  Either way, the question is too broad and not going to be grounded in fact per the guidelines set in Help Center, so it's still closeable.

Comment: Related posts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/301745

Comment: @Thoms-ward I'm very disappointed with this answer. I'm new to Linux, and I can not try if the computer is suitable for Ubuntu because I want to buy it, I do not have it yet, and I do not want to buy and find that it is not suitable.
I asked if Ubuntu would support the computer's hardware (video card, network card, wifi, touchpad, audio card, and the like).
I do not understand what the problem is with the question, and I am very disappointed with the response to my first post.

Comment: Not 20.04 or 20.10, because the Intel graphics driver is problematic with recent Linux kernels. Use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288395/system-is-unusable-after-upgrade-to-20-10-i915-gpu-hang

Comment: thank you.......

Comment: @CarlH there was update for that...

Comment: @mi12 the problem is if everyone asked "Does [random computer] work with Ubuntu?" we'd have a billion opinion driven questions not necessarily any guarantees on any real answers.  We tend to *discourage* those types of questions, which is why you got the response you've gotten.  As for your system, it *may* be able to support Ubuntu (I've had good luck with Dell systems and Ubuntu support) but there's no way to **guarantee** it'll work.

Comment: @chv It is still an outstanding issue. My laptop has Intel graphics and the i915 driver, and does not work at all with 20.10.