# Black screen after updating ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.10

My laptop was running ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10 in dual boot mode. Yesterday ubuntu asked for an update. So I updated it from 20.04 LTS to 20.10 the update was automatic. After finishing update it asked me to restart. I have restarted and now there is a black screen. Windows 10 is loading. But when I click ubuntu this black screen comes. I am confused what to do next.

[Black Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPfYG.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried pressing ENTER?

Comment: yes. Can access terminal. What to do next?

Comment: First, try typing `exit` and then press ENTER. If it does the same thing, follow the instructions to reboot. If you still get the same thing, review the journalctl errors and post those to your question.

Comment: Were you running Nvidia drivers?

Comment: No. I have intel drivers for my laptop's integrated graphics.

Comment: Okay, then we know that's not the issue.

Comment: @mchid  There is a known issue with Intel graphics drivers and recent kernels. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288395/system-is-unusable-after-upgrade-to-20-10-i915-gpu-hang

Comment: @CarlH I added a possible answer to that question (a known fix for i915 driver crashes).

Comment: Also, [take a look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190075/167115) which might help but we won't know unless we know what `journalctl -xb` says (the errors are usually in red).

Answer (score 0):

After you log in and get a terminal.

First, try typing `exit` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If it does the same thing, follow the instructions to reboot. You can either run:

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
systemctl reboot
```

If you still get the same thing, review the journalctl errors by running the following command and post those to your question:

```
journalctl -xb
```

The last thing I would suggest would be to run the following commands to finish any unfinished updates:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then, reboot.

Please post any errors.