# Black patches on home screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, upgrade, 20.04

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5530 laptop with 8 GB RAM, integrated 4 GB Intel graphics and a 1 TB HDD. I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 yesterday. On starting my laptop, the desktop wallpaper has many blackish-yellow squares all over the screen, as shown here:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Also, some of the icons on desktop disappears and sometimes the laptop freezes.

What should I do? Is Ubuntu 20.04 still unstable or is it some issue of my laptop. Can someone help?

Comment: There are known problems with Intel graphics and newer Linux kernels. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288395/system-is-unusable-after-upgrade-to-20-10-i915-gpu-hang/

Comment: @CarlH I went through the link you poster and further links posted there, but none of them seemed to work. The last option remains, downgrade to 18.04. Isn't there some other option for fixing this? Also, will downgrading lead to any further problem or will it be fine?